# Azure policy for naming conventions for subnets to start with "snet", but allow subnet names like "AzureBastionSubnet", "AzureFirewallSubnet", etc

Tags: json, azure, policy, azure-policy

I'm creating an Azure policy that enforces a naming convention for my subnets. The subnets should follow the format: snet---.
To do this I used the regular expression:

```
[if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 0), equals(split(field('name'), '-')[0], 'snet')), if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 1), contains(parameters('unit'), split(field('name'), '-')[1])),  if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 2), contains(parameters('env'), split(field('name'), '-')[2])), 'isValid', 'Environment not accepted')]
```

This works as expected. However when I try to allow the creation of subnets with names like "AzureBastionSubnet", I get an error that the name should follow the format above mentioned.

Here is the code of the policy:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
          "field": "type"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "value": "(equals(field('name'),'AzureBastionSubnet')",
              "notEquals": "true"
            },
            {
              "notEquals": "isValid",
              "value": "[if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 0), equals(split(field('name'), '-')[0], 'snet')), if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 1), contains(parameters('unit'), split(field('name'), '-')[1])),  if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 2), contains(parameters('env'), split(field('name'), '-')[2])), 'isValid', 'Environment not accepted')]"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "unit": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "unit",
        "description": null
      }
    },
    "env": {
      "type": "Array",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "env",
        "description": null
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Is there an issue on how I'm expressing that the value "AzureBastionSubnet" is also allowed?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure policy for naming conventions for subnets to start with "snet", but allow subnet names like AzureBastionSubnet

Here is the updated policy to create a `subnet` with a name starting with **snet** based on the unit and environment conditions, and also allowing specific names like **AzureBastionSubnet**. In my case, I have given the `unit` name as **IT** and the `env` as **test** in the parameters

```json
    {
      "mode": "All",
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
              "field": "type"
            },
            {
              "not": {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "equals": "AzureBastionSubnet",
                    "field": "name"
                  },
                  {
                    "notEquals": "isValid",
                    "value": "[if(and(greaterOrEquals(length(split(field('name'), '-')), 1), equals(split(field('name'), '-')[0], 'snet'), contains(parameters('unit'), split(field('name'), '-')[1]), contains(parameters('env'), split(field('name'), '-')[2])), 'isValid', 'Environment not accepted')]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "unit": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "unit",
            "description": null
          }
        },
        "env": {
          "type": "Array",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "env",
            "description": null
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The policy allows the creation of a subnet only if the specified conditions are met. For example, '**snet-IT-test**' is considered valid, while **'snet-IT-demo'** is not valid. Similarly, **'AzureBastionSubnet'** is valid, but **'AzureBastionSubnet1'** is not valid. The policy allows subnet creation only under valid conditions; otherwise, it denies the creation of the subnet.

**Subnet result in Portal**

[image]

[image]